# Laravel 5.7 route with name not working but simple routing is working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Laravel 5.7 route with name not working but simple routing is working, i tried and found lot of answers but nothing is working for me , please help me on this

i tried this

```
Route::get('jobs/jobs-search', 'JobsController@job_listing')->name('jobssearch');
```

also tried this

```
Route::get('jobs/jobs-search', array('as' => 'jobssearch', 'uses' => 'JobsController@job_listing'));

Working with url: {{ url('jobs/jobs-search') }} //http://localhost/mzd/jobs/jobs-search
Not working accessing name rout {{ route('jobssearch') }} this show 404 page not found //http://localhost/mzd/jobssearch
```

i am using xampp 7.2.10 with laravel 5.7
this is my .htaccess

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# Disable index view
 Options -Indexes

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

[Image of my routes please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhoFg.png)

Comment: your route clearly says name is jobs.jobssearch so try `route('jobs.jobssearch');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url that is being generated is different that's why you get 404, if you notice `jobs` is missing from your named route. So try this:

```
Route::get('/jobs/jobs-search', 'JobsController@job_listing')->name('jobssearch');
```

Notice the starting `/`. And then check what `route('jobssearch')` will return.

--- EDIT

Based on your routes you need to use `route('jobs.jobssearch');`

Comment: Check your routes with `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: screenshot link attached please check

Comment: @nakov now this is my route

Route::get('/jobs/jobs-search', 'JobsController@job_listing')->name('jobs.jobssearch');

and this is my url

http://localhost/mzd/jobssearch
but still 404 page not found
but this is working http://localhost/mzd/jobs/jobs-search

Comment: @7544325632 when you type `php artisan route:list` there is a column name which contains the name for your route, so you should use that one. You didn't had to change `->name('jobs.jobssearch')` you might have a group that adds the `jobs` prefix to your routes.

Comment: @nakov i removed jobs from name and make route like this
Route::get('/jobs/jobs-search', 'JobsController@job_listing')->name('jobssearch'); and accessing it route('jobs.jobssearch'); but still i am receiving 404, tried everything every pattern

Comment: okay, so what does the name column show for that route when you list all routes?

Comment: then use `route('jobssearch');`

Comment: still same 404 after using route('jobssearch');

Comment: can you show us job_listing method ? route looks fine

Answer (score 0):

If you verify the image of your routes, you should use `route('jobs.jobssearch');`

Comment: i tried route('jobs.jobssearch') and route('jobssearch') both are not working